# Where can I find documentation about CXF / AXIS service list web page?

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, cxf, axis

I need to customize web pages service list, that are the pages listing the service, operation , namespaces and wsdls deployed under the same war.

- In CXF page starts with "Available SOAP services"
- In Axis page starts with "And now... Some Services"

In both cases I couldn't find any official information about how to configure, manage, change or maintenance those pages, even I am not sure if "service list web page" is the right name for those pages. I am also wondering whether those pages change from version to version or remain as always, and whether depend only on the cxf/axis core, or also from other libraries.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Axis1 everything is hardcoded in `org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.reportAvailableServices(HttpServletResponse, PrintWriter, HttpServletRequest)` method. Fortunately this method is protected, so you may derive your own `AxisServlet` class and override this method

For CXF you can try setting `service-list-stylesheet` servlet init param as mentioned [here](http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/Customization-of-service-list-page-tp2797089p2800367.html)